Return All Records (With Duplicates) with certain status order in PowerBI
I have some data and it came from a manual entry CRM so it has alot of human errors. (which you will see in the Customer Stage, the status will be marked as XXX Error)
The first step that I have to do is to filter out the Customer profile which is at the latest stage in PowerBI.
Customer Stage ranking: Lead OR Lead Error -> Prospect OR Prospect Error-> Profile OR Profile Error (final stage)
Below is a piece of sample data I have (Customer profile in different stages):
enter image description here
The result I am looking for as per below (Return Customer profile at its latest stages even there are duplicates):
enter image description here
You will probably realize that there are still duplicates after the exercise, however, my goal here is not trying to de-dup but picking up the profile at their latest stages.
Lastly, if this can be done in power editor that would be great as I will need to join this table with other tables afterwards. However, measure is fine too if its not achievable in power query editor
May I know if someone can provide an idea of doing this?
Any tips are appreciated.
Thank you
I tried approached this by grouping the customer 1st, then rank the order of the stages, lastly select the Max order, but this approach only return ONE record (which I will need duplicate if it is in the same stage).

You could:

Add a custom column to give you a numeric version of your Status column.
#"Inserted conditional column"
Group By on Customer and max of the status num column.
#"Grouped rows"
Merge with previous 2 steps, and Expand.
#"Merged queries" & #"Expanded Grouped rows"

let
  Source = Table.FromRows(Json.Document(Binary.Decompress(Binary.FromText("i45WclTSUfJJTUwBUoYGSrE6EJGAovzigtTkEiDTCCLqhFBnjBBBUocqmpaZkwpkmUIEnRGaTRAiCGVmeARdkBxoChfBdCCyqIJrUVF+EULOFdVR6GJw5UCZWAA=", BinaryEncoding.Base64), Compression.Deflate)), let _t = ((type nullable text) meta [Serialized.Text = true]) in type table [Customer = _t, #"Profile Status" = _t, Asset = _t]),
  #"Changed column type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source, {{"Customer", type text}, {"Profile Status", type text}, {"Asset", Int64.Type}}, "en-US"),
  #"Inserted conditional column" = Table.AddColumn(#"Changed column type", "Profile Status num", each if Text.StartsWith([Profile Status], "Lead") then 1 else if Text.StartsWith([Profile Status], "Prospect") then 2 else if Text.StartsWith([Profile Status], "Profile") then 3 else -1, Int64.Type),
  #"Grouped rows" = Table.Group(#"Inserted conditional column", {"Customer"}, {{"Max Status", each List.Max([Profile Status num]), type nullable Int64.Type}}),
  #"Merged queries" = Table.NestedJoin(#"Grouped rows", {"Customer", "Max Status"}, #"Inserted conditional column", {"Customer", "Profile Status num"}, "Grouped rows", JoinKind.LeftOuter),
  #"Expanded Grouped rows" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(#"Merged queries", "Grouped rows", {"Profile Status", "Asset"}, {"Profile Status", "Asset"})
in
  #"Expanded Grouped rows"



you can try to create a rank column
= Table.AddColumn(Source,"Rank",each List.Count(Table.SelectRows(Source,(x)=>x[Asset]>[Asset] and x[Customer]=[Customer])[Asset])+1)


then filter the rank to 1 and delete rank column

let
    Source = Table.FromRows(Json.Document(Binary.Decompress(Binary.FromText("i45WclTSUfJJTUwBUoYGSrE6EJGAovzigtTkEiDTCCLqhFBnjBBBUocqmpaZkwpkmUIEnRGaTRAiCGVmeARdkBxoChfBdCCyqIJrUVF+EULOFVWHKYYgXANQKhYA", BinaryEncoding.Base64), Compression.Deflate)), let _t = ((type nullable text) meta [Serialized.Text = true]) in type table [Customer = _t, #"Profile Status" = _t, Asset = _t]),
    Custom1 = Table.AddColumn(Source,"Rank",each List.Count(Table.SelectRows(Source,(x)=>x[Asset]>[Asset] and x[Customer]=[Customer])[Asset])+1),
    #"Filtered Rows" = Table.SelectRows(Custom1, each [Rank] = 1),
    #"Removed Columns" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Filtered Rows",{"Rank"})
in
    #"Removed Columns"

